# Set week number based on first Monday of Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, while-loop, sql-update

I have a requirement to set the week number of a table from the first day to the first Monday to the next Monday and so on. I can easily get the first Day and first Monday of year but I do not know how to increment trough the table in 7 days intervals from the first Monday so that I can set the week number.

I have something like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET weeknumberofyear = @WeekNumber + 1
WHERE datefield = DATEADD(Day,7,(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date)         + (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 7, @Date)))
```

Comment: Can you reword your question to make it clearer?  I've read it five times, and I don't understand it.

Comment: You want to count weeks with Tuesday as the first day of the week, right? See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `datepart(week,datefield)` function gets week number based on Sunday as the first day of the week, all you have to do is check `datepart(weekday,datefield)` and if it is 1 (Sunday) or 2 (Monday), subtract 1 from the `datepart(week,datefield)` function:

```
update table
    set weeknumberofyear = datepart(week,datefield) -
        case when datepart(weekday,datefield) in(1,2) then 1 else 0 end
```

**EDIT** This doesn't account for Years when Sunday or Monday are the first day of the year. In those cases, you would get 0 for `weeknumberofyear`. To fix this, perform a second update to your table. Even though this takes two updates, I still think it is more efficient than cycling through all the records.

```
update table
    set weeknumberoftheyear = weeknumberoftheyear + 1
    where year(datefield) in(
                            select distinct year(datefield)
                            from table
                            where weeknumberoftheyear = 0
                            )
```

**EDIT** WeekNumberOfTheMonth Update - Now that we have the WeekNumberOfTheYear value, we can use a ranking function on that field to update the WeekNumberOfTheMonth column without any recursion.

```
update t
  set t.weeknumberofthemonth = u.weeknumberofthemonth
  from table t
    inner join (
      select distinct weeknumberoftheyear,
         dense_rank() over(partition by month(datefield)
         order by weeknumberoftheyear) weeknumberofthemonth
      from table ) u
        on u.weeknumberofyear = t.weeknumberofyear
```

Comment: This worked and was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I also have to do the same for Months as in the week number but I am having trouble applying this to that problem. It should be roughly the same thing right. Any ideas?

Comment: You are quite welcome! Happy to help. :)

The weeks were a bit tricky because of wanting to start the week on Tuesday, but if you are using standard month numbers, it should just be `set monthnumberoftheyear = month(datefiled)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I need to get the Week Number of Months in the same way that the code above got it for the entire year. So it should only set the weeks from 1 to 5 or however many there are for each month. If that makes sense I think you are talking more about setting the Month values. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by all the talk about "Monday", but if you're looking to get the week number from a date, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET weeknumberofyear = DATEPART(wk, datefield)
```